# How to get feedback on your question's quality?

Tags: discussion, support

I made a question on Stack Overflow that which got down-voted and closed. Even though I tried my best to improve the question's quality, it wasn't voted for reopening.

I would like to know if there is a place in Stack Overflow or here on Meta where you can discuss the particular question and get some guidance on how improve it.

I couldn't find on the forums a particular place to do this, and the help provided by the FAQ in this particular case isn't of much help since I personally think the question is OK.

If a place like this doesn't exist, I think it could be helpful for new users and non-English speakers to get some guidance on how to create questions properly.

---

**Pd:** In case you want to check the question I'm talking about on Stack Overflow, you can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9311690/382059

Comment: Ugh. Did this really get downvoted and closed because of the use of the word "encryption" instead of "hashing"? (Meta, right here, is the place, by the way.)

Comment: @Pekka do you think replacing every instance of "encrypt" or "decrypt" with hash will fix the question? I don't.

Comment: @Conrad fair enough, but then somebody in the comment thread should have said so (instead of having an endless anal discussion about how encryption != hashing)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, an answer to the question in your title.

[You are in the right place](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

---

**Now, some feedback:**

Based on this part

> If you were to choose the most secure method for this specific case, which one it would be and why (SHA1, SHA512, MD5, etc.)

this is a rather broad, subjective question. It asks the answerer to pick their own preference and explain why (state and support their opinion).

Based on the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), this is not allowed because of 2 conditions:

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

It may not be your *motivation* to participate in a discussion, but with every answer being an opinion with a supporting argument, and people having different opinions, it is more of a discussion that a straight answer.

Secondly

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

Since the question asks "which would you choose?" and "why?", every answer is technically correct, so it is not a good fit for Stackoverflow's Q&A model.

Perhaps you could make it a better fit if you select a specific hashing method and ask a targeted question about that (as long as it's not something you can simply look up elsewhere online).

Comment: Thanks Jim. Now I can fix the question. :)

Comment: I updated the question. I think it's more straightforward now thanks to your help. But I don't think I can get 5 people to vote to reopen it, so... should I just forget about it?