# Should we ask questions with duplicate question titles?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, title

When I search for a solution, there is an exact question title but the user may ask a different question related to his/her own problem and that wouldn't solve ours. For example:

> **How to detect OS from javascript?**
>
> I want to know If the browser is running from Window OS.

But If I have a different OS issue, should I ask a question with exactly the same title so that I could get good answers?

Comment: Questions with exactly duplicate titles are not allowed by the system, so there is no need to worry about this. Simply try to word the title more tailored toward your question.

Comment: as a side note, please don't ask questions of the form "How to ____?" (that is not a question)

Comment: Why shouldn't he ask questions in that form? It seems to be the preferred form according to this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19999/should-question-titles-be-phrased-as-questions-a-straw-poll?rq=1

Comment: @BBog I believe Jim is saying that "How to ___?" is broken English. Questions are preferred, but should be written correctly as, for example, "How do I ___?"

Comment: Ah, I understand, that's the statement form :D Thank you for the clarification

Comment: That's just quibbling, considering that you have [answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122615/166277) such questions in the past

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not ask a question with duplicate title. Stack Overflow will not allow you to ask question with duplicate title.

As @Jim told in [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147486/should-we-ask-questions-with-duplicate-question-titles#comment423099_147486). Simply try to word the title more tailored toward your question.

Comment: Unfortunately one misspelled word "helps" you get the question accepted. And then the spelling can not be corrected. Is this a feature or  bug? ;-)

Comment: @BoPersson I think it is drawback.